# How to perform update on a table with values in its current field

Tags: mysql

How to perform update on a table with values in its current field.

already implemented some trial code, but generating error.

```
UPDATE T_CONFIG
    SET MIN_REQUIRED_DATE = MIN(select REQUIRED_DATE FROM (select TABLE_NAME from T_CONFIG ))
where MIN_REQUIRED_DATE ='';
```

`MIN_REQUIRED_DATE` will get the minimum date from the Table it get in nested Select.

Comment: Are your column names all in UPPER CASE?

Comment: What error is it that you are getting?

Comment: "generating error"...what error, exactly? Clearly if we're going to help you it would be a lot simpler if you tell us what the error is, instead of guessing. Don't leave out important information.

Comment: Yes all the column names are in upper case

Comment: MySQL best practise is for all column names to be lower case and all MySQL instructives to be in Upper Case. At first glance it seems you've got the inverse for this and it's harder to read off-the-bat. This won't cause you errors but can cause human-error and is worth knowing for when you update your SQL `;-)`

Comment: error receiving as syntax error:   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the exact syntax error and in what part of the SQL query the error is generated. chees

Comment: Maybe you want `WHERE MIN_REQUIRED_DATE=NULL`? That's not TEXT is it?

Comment: Hi Martin, I have created dummy Tables in my database to meet the real requirement. so i have kept names of column in Uppercase. the error generating here is related to Syntax. Do i have to use Dynamic SQL? if yes... how to write the code for it there?

Comment: Hi StackSlave, even WHERE MIN_REQUIRED_DATE=NULL is not wrking

Comment: @Sonam: the 'edit' button is invented to update your question with the info on how you exactly created this table in your database, together with some sample data.

Comment: Could you try this `UPDATE "T_CONFIG" SET "MIN_REQUIRED_DATE" = MIN(select "REQUIRED_DATE" FROM (select "TABLE_NAME" from "T_CONFIG" )) where "MIN_REQUIRED_DATE" = NULL;` just to make sure the error is not due to your column naming. I just escaped all the column and table names. Also could you check if the subquery works on its own.

Comment: Hi Omega, the error generating is not related to Column naming. i am able to get normal select query on the same table and same field. error seems to be logical. with your code snippet too i get the same kind of error:  Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Hi Folks, any idea how to go for it. Couldn't find a resolution any where. Can we do it via procedure? if yes could you help how to?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, looking into your query

```
UPDATE T_CONFIG
SET MIN_REQUIRED_DATE = MIN(select REQUIRED_DATE FROM (select TABLE_NAME from 
T_CONFIG ))
where MIN_REQUIRED_DATE ='';
```

and focusing on this section

```
MIN(select REQUIRED_DATE FROM (select TABLE_NAME from 
T_CONFIG ))
```

I notice 2 problems:

1) you are trying to retrieve a column `REQUIRED_DATE` from the select statement `select TABLE_NAME from T_CONFIG` that only return a column name `TABLE_NAME`. which I think that is not your intention

2) The placing of the `MIN` function is wrong

So, based on what I can deduce from your predicament. Your solution should be something like this..

```
UPDATE T_CONFIG
SET MIN_REQUIRED_DATE = (select MIN(REQUIRED_DATE) FROM (select * from 
T_CONFIG) a)
where MIN_REQUIRED_DATE ='';
```

This should set all rows of column `MIN_REQUIRED_DATE` that is an empty string to the Minimum date value of that Table `T_CONFIG`.

NOTE: you might want to reconfirm this `MIN_REQUIRED_DATE` "Datatype", I personally do not remember a date type column can be an empty string. based on my memory, I can only remember it taking an actual date value or Null.

Comment: Hi Ryan, Coming to the two points mentioned by you. for case 1> My intention is exactly to Fetch the TABLE_NAME column of the table as it stores different table for different rows in data preview of T_CONFIG. suppose i get KNA1 table for record1, then the MIN_REQUIRED_DATE will get the minimum value of date field (say Start_date) from KNA1-Start_date. Yes placing of Min function i have adjusted as suggested by you, still the purpose is not being served.

Comment: Ok Folks,  so i will give what my real use case is: I have a Table named T_Config which has columns named as ( TABLE_NAME, NUMERIC_FIELDS,DATE_FIELDS, REQUIRED_DATE, MIN_REQUIRED_DATE). The data type of all the fields are Varchar. example of one record for this table is (T_LFA1;; COST_PRICE,SELL_PRICE,DISCOUNT,MRP START_DATE,END_DATE,PACKAGED_DATE,DELIVERY_DATE;; START_DATE;; NULL). Here ;; i have given to specify segregator for value of different fields.

Comment: Now my req lets say just for one record is, i have to see START_DATE and see it is coming from T_LFA1 table so i would go to this table and get the minimum value of T_LFA1-START_DATE and would populate that value in T_CONFIG-MIN_REQUIRED_DATE.

Comment: similarly for other records, it would be a set of different table and different date field of that table i would have to see for minimum and populate that minimum value of date field in  T_Config for that record